# AngularJS - expression as function parameter in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Can I pass expressions from `ng-repeat` as parameters to a function attached to `ng-click`?

This

```
<a ng-repeat="foo in bar" ng-click="foobar(foo.link)">{{foo.name}}</a>
```

and this

```
<a ng-repeat="foo in bar" ng-click="foobar({{foo.link}})">{{foo.name}}</a>
```

doesn't work.

Link to jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6g3QX/11/

Comment: The first should work. Do you have a fiddle reproducing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the function `foobar` that is being called.

```
$scope.foobar = function(val) {
    alert(val);
}
```

I've updated your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6g3QX/12/

Comment: I got confused by the expression not being expanded in the HTML output. The issue actually was that I was expecting 2 parameters, and was passing only 1.